# Cannot find module express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

Im trying to run an express application and im getting the following error:

> module.js:471
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './controllers'

this is my app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
//let passport = require('passport');
//let session = require('express-session');
const app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('index.html');
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
})

app.use('/',require('./controllers'));

/*
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
*/
app.listen(3000);
```

I would like to know why im getting this error

this is my application structure:

[image: Structure]

Comment: You cannot require the controllers directory. You need to specify which .js file you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require a directory like this:

```
app.use('/', require('./controllers'));
```

...you are technically looking for **./controllers/index.js**:

You would have to add the file name, for example:

```
app.use('/', require('./controllers/route'));
```